Create Choclatey Package Internalizer on Linux host
Is it possible to create a chcolatey package internalizer server on a linux host () instead on a windows host?
As far as I understand the internalizer will download the packages from the community servers and the internalizer provides it as a repo source.
Is it possible to utelize a gitlab instance as a package internalizer? I now that the package registry of gitlab kind of support nuget, but I can't find any solid information about it.
